# How to create auto popup when I access a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popupwindow

I was trying to create an auto popup when I access a web store that is developed in Shopif

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
  function popup(mylink, windowname) { 
    if (! window.focus)return true;
    var href;
    if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href=mylink;
    else href=mylink.href; 
    window.open(href, windowname, 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes'); 
    return false; 
  }
</SCRIPT>

<BODY onLoad="popup('autopopup.html', 'ad')">
```

I have the above code for Popup Windows Opening Automatically. However, I need assistance on how to make this work on and this is the website that I am trying to work it on https://petit-tapis.co.uk

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Scopey said, modern browsers prevent this behavior from auto occurring. You can however add a click or if you want people to take action first before doing anything else, you can for example add an overlay that blocks any other functionality (but I can tell you that this kills user experience).

Maybe say more what your goal is. Why do you want this extra window to open? What benefit is there in doing this (what do you and what does the user get out of it)?

edit: See my comment below. I also slapped together a very simple version of what I am talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/uthhvu8d/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime, inventore esse aliquam nostrum? Cupiditate provident, delectus, minus voluptatum natus fugiat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus temporibus vitae quibusdam maxime natus fugiat quis amet sed perferendis quod.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam nostrum consequatur animi quod rem eos nihil obcaecati repellat. At, accusamus.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function showOverlay() {
  $('.overlay').show()
}
setTimeout(showOverlay, 2000)
```

Comment: Hi Falk, Is it possible to add a pop up after page load ?

Comment: When user visits my website , in few seconds a sign up form should auto populate. This is what I am looking for.

Hope this answers to your question !

Comment: Hey, yes, you can set a timeout that starts when the page is loaded and after lets say 3-5 seconds later you append an overlay. You can do this really easy in jQuery if you want to write by hand or you can probably get a plugin that does it for you.

Comment: Hi Falk, I am not looking for any plug-ins as they don't support Single Opt-In Mailchimp integration.  So, I have created form under Wufoo and downloaded the code for that form and had a Shopify store where I have to place that form on home page. Whenever some visits, it should display after few seconds.  For EX : https://www.ellsworthandivey.com/

The above website shows how exactly I want that popup to auto populate bu they're using Mailchimp pop up form.

Comment: Thank you so much Falk! It's really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully, modern browsers prevent this behaviour from happening.

Any `window.open` must occur only as a direct result of a user triggered event - such as a mouse click or similar.

Answer (score 0):

As @Scopey said browsers stop you opening a pop up window however you could use the HTML5 Dialog and the dialog overlays in the browser have a play you can even open it model if you wanted will take a little longer to get it to work but it's anotion for you

```
<dialog id="dialog">
    <iframe src="autopopup.html" />
</dialog>
```